# How to produce a GUI output screen on tkinter that will print database search with corresponding labels?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hi I need to produce a tkinter GUI screen that will output the search results. I have already established the screen and the labels but the thing that I am struggling with is printing the correct information next to the relevant labels.

Here is my code...

```
def search_button():
global e1, e2, e3, new_db
original = e1.get()
original_2 = e2.get()
original_3 = e3.get()

args = (original, original, original, original, original, original_2, original_2, original_2, original_2, original_2, original_3, original_3, original_3, original_3, original_3)
cursor = new_db.execute('''SELECT Name, Method, Ing_1, Ing_2, Ing_3, Ing_4, Ing_5, Time
FROM Recipes_Dtls WHERE Ing_1=? or Ing_2=? or Ing_3=? or Ing_4=? or Ing_5=? or Ing_1=?
or Ing_2=? or Ing_3=? or Ing_4=? or Ing_5=? or Ing_1=? or Ing_2=? or Ing_3=? or Ing_4=? or
Ing_5=?''',args)

for row in cursor:
     print ("Name of Recipe = ", row[0])
     print ("Method = ", row[1])
    print ("Ingredient1 = ", row[2])
     print ("Ingredient2 = ", row[3])
     print ("Ingredient3 = ", row[4])
     print ("Ingredient4 = ", row[5])
     print ("Ingredient5 = ", row[6])
     print ("Time = ", row[7], "\n")
```

Please can you give me a few hints or even better the code that I need to do. Thanks for your help... I will be indebted to you forever! :)

Comment: use [Grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).

Comment: The best thing you can do at this point, since you don't know anything  about tkinter, is to spend a day working through a tkinter tutorial.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no attempt at solving the problem by the author